# Calculate total in cart is not working in angular 6

Tags: angular

If the Quantity get increment or decrement it should be reflect on total amount.
Cart.ts:

```
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {

     cart: Cart[] = [];
     private calculateCart(cart:Cart){
            cart.itemsTotal = cart.items
                                  .map((item) => item.Quantity * this.products.find((p) => p.ProductId === item.ProductId).Price)
                                  .reduce((previous, current) => previous + current, 0);
            cart.deliveryTotal = cart.deliveryOptionId ?
                                  this.deliveryOptions.find((x) => x.id === cart.deliveryOptionId).price : 0;
            cart.grossTotal = cart.itemsTotal + cart.deliveryTotal;
            return cart.grossTotal;
      }
```

cart.html:

```
<div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <i class="fa fa-inr"></i>&nbsp; {{(cart | async).grossTotal}}
</div>
```

cart.model:

```
import { CartItem } from "./cart-item.model";

export class Cart {
    items : CartItem[];
    itemsTotal : number;
    grossTotal: number = 0;
    deliveryTotal: number = 0;
    deliveryOptionId: string;

    ProductId: number;
    Option: string;
    Quantity: number;
}
```

If the product is add to cart,total is not added in the cart.I have tried a lot  related to it but failed to get the output.How to achieve this

Comment: cart is and array, so why are you using `async` pipe for that like it would be `Observable` idk. Why cart is array is another mistery.

Answer (score 0):

```
   cart: Cart;
```

insteed of

```
   cart: Cart[] = [];
```

and

```
{{cart.grossTotal}}
```

After all, you have only 1 cart not many of them right?

Comment: It depends upon the customer add the products

Comment: So can I have 10 carts ?:>

Comment: You can add 10 cart items

Comment: Buy you have mutliple carts

Comment: I was removed the array as pointed above i did not get output

Answer (score 0):

I guess your cart: Cart[] is actually of type Cart, because you have one cart, not multiple as @Antoniossss pointed out.

You're also not modifying your cart instance you reference in your template. After calculating the grossTotal of your (local) cart, you need to update the cart instance that is available in your template with `this.cart = cart;`.

I built a little stackblitz showing how it could work: https://angular-tfihau.stackblitz.io

Comment: I update my code with the change u said,but it still not working.

Comment: Is it to be placed inside the calculate function,right?

Comment: Yes, you should put it there. I added a simple example to the answer.